# Not able to upload file using react js through Springboot API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload list of files simultaneously but not able to do it. I get an error that file is not found, although file object is present but in the request it shows that it is an `[object Object]`, although it should be a file binary.

That's how my code is

```
data.forEach(element => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    data.actualFiles.forEach(
        file => {
            if (file.fileName === element.attachmentUIDTO.fileName) {
                formData.append('file', file);
            }
        }
    )
    
    const resUpload = api.post(`${serviceEnpoints.PRFS_UPLOAD}`, formData);
}
```

The main issue is happening when I am iterating it in list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the request **"Content-Type"** to **"multipart/form-data"**

In **Axios** you can do it like this:

```
const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: endpoint,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
        params: {},
        data: formData
      });
```

And since you are sending several files, I would recommend using the array notation when calling the **append** method.

Like this:

```
...

formData.append('files[]', file);

...
```